# Scheduled Notifications in Flutter using local notifications

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I am working on scheduled notifications. When I click on the press button I am getting a message in debug console saying "Notification Scheduled for TimeOfDay(19:10)" but there is no notification popping up on my emulator screen. A notification should pop up at the time that I entered using the pick button

This is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  NotificationService().initNotification();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'flutter demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TimeOfDay _timeOfDay = const TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 30);

  void _timePicker() {
    showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now())
        .then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() {
          _timeOfDay = value;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: _timePicker,
              child: const Text(
                'PICK',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('press'),
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint('Notification Scheduled for $_timeOfDay');
                NotificationService().scheduleNotification(
                    title: 'Schedule notification',
                    body: '$_timeOfDay',
                    scheduledNotificationDateTime: _timeOfDay);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('panda');

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    await notificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  AndroidNotificationDetails notificationDetails() {
    return const AndroidNotificationDetails('channel id', 'channel name',
        importance: Importance.max);
  }

  NotificationDetails buildNotificationDetails() {
    final androidDetails = notificationDetails();
    return NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payload}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(id, title, body,
        NotificationDetails(android: await notificationDetails()));
  }

  Future<void> scheduleNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payload,
    required TimeOfDay scheduledNotificationDateTime,
  }) async {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    var scheduledDateTime = DateTime(
      now.year,
      now.month,
      now.day,
      scheduledNotificationDateTime.hour,
      scheduledNotificationDateTime.minute,
    );
// Ensure that the scheduledDateTime is in the future
    if (scheduledDateTime.isBefore(now)) {
      // If it's in the past, add one day
      scheduledDateTime = scheduledDateTime.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }

    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      TZDateTime.from(scheduledDateTime, tz.local),
      buildNotificationDetails(),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
}
```